# Could user control be stand alone as a form?

Tags: .net, forms

I cannot find a way how to do that. I assume it needs to be child of different control?

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows Forms component or the ASP.NET Webforms?

Comment: I think you have to give some context here.

Comment: Why can't you just create a container form and dock your control in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add it to an empty form, which is simple if you use the designer.  Assuming you don't want to use the designer, you can still do this using code.  Something like:

```
MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl();

Form containerForm = new Form();
containerForm.ClientSize = control.Size;
containerForm.Controls.Add(control);

control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
containerForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Justin is right. If you want, you can create extension methods:

```
new MyUserControl().ShowInForm();
new MyUserControl().ShowInForm((frm)=>{
    frm.Text = "My user control";
});

public static class MyExtensions {
    public static void ShowInForm(this Control ctl) {
        ShowInForm(ctl, (Action<Form>)null);
    }
    public static void ShowInForm(this Control ctl, Action<Form> initFormAction) {
        // removes control from previous container
        ctl.Parent = null;

        var frm = new Form();
        frm.ClientSize = ctl.Size;
        ctl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frm.Controls.Add(ctl);
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

You can also create extension methods for show in dialog windows and whatever else variants.